# Trying to load advertiser script tags asynchronously - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some banner zones set up on advertisespace.com - I'm trying to load the script tags using jquery so they load after the page has loaded. However its not working. Here is my code to do this.

Here is the function I use to include the script tag:

```
function jsinclude(file, dom) {
   if (document.createElement && document.getElementsByTagName) {
     if(dom=='undefined')
        var dom = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
     script.setAttribute('src', file);

     script.setAttribute('charset',"utf-8");

     dom.appendChild(script);
   } else {
     alert('Your browser can\'t deal with the DOM standard. That means it\'s old. Go fix it!');
   }
 }
```

ANd here is how I am calling the function:

```
$(function(){
jsinclude('http://ads.advertisespace.com/somethingsomething.js', document.getElementById('location-of-banner-1'));


jsinclude('http://ads.advertisespace.com/somethingsomething.js', document.getElementById('location-of-banner-2'));

})
```

The result is that the script tag is inserted in the correct place but the banners doesn't show i.e the code in the script file referred to is never executed. How can I fix this.

Comment: undefined is a State not a String!

Comment: The dom is not the `head` element. The example `.js` file also does not contain JavaScript code. Does your real one contain JavaScript code? Lastly, an advertisement service should not make alerts appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) so why not make use of its advantages.

The dom is not the head element, and doing `dom == 'undefined'` checks whether the variable `dom` is equal to the string `'undefined'`. You must have set that explicitly and that's probably not the case. Anyway, there is one `head` element so it's not necessary to pass it to the function - the function can handle that itself.

Also, checking for DOM functions is not applicable these days. We live in 2011, all browsers have these functions included.

```
function jsinclude(file) {
     var script = $("<script>", { type:    'text/javascript',
                                  src:     file,
                                  charset: 'utf-8' });
     $('head').append(script);
}
```